# What's the efficient algorithm to determine whether convex constraints have nonempty feasible region?

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization

Given a bunch of [affine equations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineEquation.html) and [convex inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), how to efficiently determine whether these convex constraints have nonempty [feasible region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_region)? If nonempty, just need to return one feasible point.

Just need to tell me the name of this algorithm or the terminology of this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Can you compute subgradients of the constraints?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, assume every constraint is smooth.

Comment: Broadly convex problems are considered 'solvable' from a practical perspective. In this case the $\max$ of the constraints is convex, just minimise that until it is $\le 0$.